# converter conteúdo no input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Galera uso um script em javascript para converter tudo o que digito, dentro do input para maiúsculo.

Porem tenho um input específico a onde não posso alterar seu conteúdo. Como posso fazer isso?

Segue o código:

```js
// Converte minusculas em maiusculas
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('input', function() {

    // Armazena posição corrente do cursor
    var start = this.selectionStart,
      end = this.selectionEnd;
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

    // Restaura posição armazenada anteriormente.
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' name='video'>
<input type='text' name='video'>
<input type='text' name='video'>
<input type='text' name='video'>


<input type='text' name='nao_alterar'>
```

Comment: Mas onde quer apareça o texto em maiusculo?

Comment: em todos os input, menos no input name='nao_alterar'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criar um evento executado em todos os inputs excepto naquele cujo nome é `nao_alterar`. Faça:

```js
$('input').not('[name="nao_alterar"]').on('input', function() {

// Armazena posição corrente do cursor
var start = this.selectionStart,
  end = this.selectionEnd;
this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

// Restaura posição armazenada anteriormente.
this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' name='video'>
<input type='text' name='video'>
<input type='text' name='video'>
<input type='text' name='video'>


<input type='text' name='nao_alterar' placeholder="não alterar">
```

Comment: bom tinha que ser usando o código que eu postei, pois ele armazena o local do cursor.

Comment: desculpe. vou fazer

Comment: Editado @HugoBorges

Comment: muito bom, vlw mesmo. Tem como verificar o nome de forma ao contrário? Tupi assim ele ser executado para todos os nomes menos para o name='nao_alterar' ?

Comment: poderia só `$('input[name="video"]').on('click', ...`, e retirava o `.not(...)`

Comment: perfeito amigo, muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @HugoBorges isso foi exatamente o que fiz. Todos os inputs excepto onde o nome é "nao_alterar", `$('input').not('[name="nao_alterar"]')...`

Comment: De nada @HugoBorges